# Index map values

Tags: solr

I have data in which field have following java data types.

What would be the best way to index such kind of data.

Thanks,

```
field_a   map<string,string>

field b   map<string,array<string>>
```

How to define schema.xml for it

Comment: How would you like to search for the data ? Say document1 has map1 in field_a and document2 has map2 in field_a , how do you plan to retrieve the documents ?

Comment: I have not thought about all the search patterns , but at min i can think is find me all customers which had this issue in past. Issue details are stored in the map and customer is the unique id for the document. Do you suggest to flatten the data and then index ? or any other way

Comment: From what I gather , I would not recommend using solr in this case. I would prefer to have MongoDB which is a document store NoSql datastore and in that you can convert the map to a JSON and persist and retrieve it. You can also look at ElasticSearch to do the same. I am not very sure about your requirements , so if you can share some more details , I can give you a better recommendation

Comment: Hi , We have a hive table which has set of fields in schema as string , string , int , map<string,string> , map<string,array<string>> . We want to index this data. Please suggest your views

Answer (score 0):

Currently Solr doesn't support map type field type. So, you can not query on some particular key inside the map and retrieve its value. I don't know whether it'll be helpful you or not, but I can suggest you a way to keep this in Solr.

You can store the map in a field as a json formatted string. Say, document1 has map1 in field_a and document2 has map2 in field_a. Now, you keep some distinct data related to each map to their corresponding documents. When you want to query, query on those fields in stead of the maps. Then in the search result, when you retrieve the json formatted string, parse it in your application and get the values.

Hope this will help.